# Browsers segfault regularly (chrome, firefox, brave)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, crash, browser, segmentation-fault

I have a laptop (Lenovo Lenovo IP 5 15ARE05) only running ubuntu 23.04. I installed ubuntu on it and restored a backup on it.

Since start web related content keeps crashing. Firefox, vscode, chrome, Brave etc. crashes regularly. No other content crashes. The segfaults are often sudden and happen without any warning. Sometimes a tab crashes, sometimes the computer dies completely. Usually the computer freezes and needs to be turned off. It is more likely to happen when reopening the laptop when it has been in standby but seems to be random. Non web related processes don't crash.

When a process freezes killing it via terminal doesn't work. I can run "kill PID" in terminal but the process doesn't disappear. Restarting the browser can be difficult and the browser is much more likely to crash again after restarting it.

I have run memtest, hardware diagnostics, it works with a live USB and I have googled every error message I can find.

Examples in syslog:

```
May  7 09:58:56 name kernel: [  715.197846] brave[22435]: segfault at 2c06c6 ip 000055b9e6b61082 sp 00007ffed3c028d0 error 4 in brave[55b9e5f05000+ae8d000]
May  7 09:58:56 name kernel: [  715.197868] Code: 8b b5 58 fd ff ff 84 c0 0f 85 3a fe ff ff 31 db e9 45 fe ff ff cc cc cc 55 48 89 e5 41 56 53 48 39 fe 74 5d 48 89 d3 49 89 f6 <48> 63 76 2c 48 01 f6 48 23 35 e8 d9 bf 0a e8 db ff ff ff 49 8b 06
May  7 09:58:56 name brave-browser.desktop[7037]: [0507/095856.823068:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir /home/name/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/attachments/312f076b-6fd7-40dd-be50-60a1bc5bfd6a: No such file or directory (2)
```

Firefox:

```
May  7 10:20:28 name kernel: [ 2007.105856] Isolated Web Co[47300]: segfault at 2d0e41e34f00 ip 00007fc688ad104c sp 00007fff30404c10 error 4 in libxul.so[7fc6848ee000+5bd6000]
May  7 10:20:28 name kernel: [ 2007.105871] Code: 04 83 4e 8d 24 f8 4e 8d 34 bb 46 8b 2c bb 45 85 ed 0f 84 89 02 00 00 44 89 e8 83 e0 fe 44 39 d8 0f 85 df 00 00 00 49 8b 3c 24 <48> 8b 07 48 89 c1 48 c1 e9 20 4c 39 c1 0f 85 c8 00 00 00 48 89 54
```

```
May  7 15:19:16 name firefox.desktop[102535]: message repeated 10 times: [ [Child 102535, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-mu7WaD/firefox-113.0+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
May  7 15:19:17 name gnome-shell[6122]: Launching DING process
May  7 15:19:17 name nautilus[112857]: Could not delete '.meta.isrunning': No such file or directory
May  7 15:19:18 name rtkit-daemon[3301]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
May  7 15:19:18 name rtkit-daemon[3301]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
May  7 15:19:18 name dbus-daemon[5932]: [session uid=1000 pid=5932] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.381' (uid=1000 pid=113584 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
May  7 15:19:18 name dbus-daemon[5932]: [session uid=1000 pid=5932] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
May  7 15:19:18 name gnome-shell[6122]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
May  7 15:19:18 name gnome-shell[6122]: DING: GNOME nautilus 43.0
May  7 15:19:18 name wpa_supplicant[2723]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-60 noise=9999 txrate=78000
May  7 15:19:18 name firefox.desktop[103357]: [Child 103357, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-mu7WaD/firefox-113.0+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
May  7 15:19:18 name firefox.desktop[103357]: message repeated 4 times: [ [Child 103357, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-mu7WaD/firefox-113.0+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
```

```
12:25:27 name firefox_firefox.desktop[54880]: [Child 54880, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
12:26:21 name firefox_firefox.desktop[54880]: message repeated 25 times: [ [Child 54880, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
12:27:21 name rtkit-daemon[3537]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
12:29:22 name rtkit-daemon[3537]: message repeated 7 times: [ Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.]
12:29:23 name firefox_firefox.desktop[61162]: [Child 61162, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
12:29:23 name firefox_firefox.desktop[61162]: message repeated 8 times: [ [Child 61162, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
12:29:26 name rtkit-daemon[3537]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
12:29:26 name rtkit-daemon[3537]: message repeated 3 times: [ Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.]
12:29:26 name rtkit-daemon[3537]: Successfully made thread 63383 of process 63215 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
12:29:26 name rtkit-daemon[3537]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
12:29:27 name rtkit-daemon[3537]: message repeated 4 times: [ Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.]
12:29:28 name firefox_firefox.desktop[16680]: ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 63461
12:29:28 name firefox_firefox.desktop[16680]: ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
12:29:28 name firefox_firefox.desktop[63461]: ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
12:29:29 name kernel: [ 2733.780233] audit: type=1400 audit(1685096969.081:173): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/proc/16680/environ" pid=63461 comm="firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[63420]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[63394]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[19105]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[45754]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[63219]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[45587]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[34998]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[58654]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[61839]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[61162]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[33642]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[17727]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[63215]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[57033]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[17077]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[45736]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name firefox_firefox.desktop[46353]: Exiting due to channel error.
12:29:29 name crashreporter[63462]: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
12:29:29 name kernel: [ 2733.973964] audit: type=1326 audit(1685096969.273:174): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.firefox.firefox pid=63462 comm="crashreporter" exe="/snap/firefox/2667/usr/lib/firefox/crashreporter" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7f979071d73d code=0x50000
12:29:31 name firefox_firefox.desktop[63462]: Failed to open curl lib from binary, use libcurl.so instead
12:29:31 name firefox[63518]: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
12:29:31 name kernel: [ 2735.901464] audit: type=1326 audit(1685096971.201:175): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.firefox.firefox pid=63518 comm="firefox" exe="/snap/firefox/2667/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7fb59a5f573d code=0x50000
12:29:31 name firefox_firefox.desktop[63518]: ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
12:29:31 name firefox_firefox.desktop[63518]: ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
12:29:31 name firefox_firefox.desktop[63518]: amdgpu: os_same_file_description couldn't determine if two DRM fds reference the same file description.
12:29:31 name firefox_firefox.desktop[63518]: If they do, bad things may happen!
12:29:31 name kernel: [ 2736.252399] audit: type=1326 audit(1685096971.553:176): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.firefox.firefox pid=63518 comm="Renderer" exe="/snap/firefox/2667/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7fb59a5f573d code=0x50000
12:29:31 name firefox_firefox.desktop[63518]: ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
12:29:31 name kernel: [ 2736.281078] audit: type=1326 audit(1685096971.581:177): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.firefox.firefox pid=63518 comm="firefox" exe="/snap/firefox/2667/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7fb59a5f573d code=0x50000
12:29:31 name kernel: [ 2736.281093] audit: type=1326 audit(1685096971.581:178): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.firefox.firefox pid=63518 comm="firefox" exe="/snap/firefox/2667/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7fb59a5f573d code=0x50000
12:29:31 name rtkit-daemon[3537]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
12:29:31 name rtkit-daemon[3537]: message repeated 5 times: [ Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.]
12:29:31 name rtkit-daemon[3537]: Successfully made thread 63835 of process 63518 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
12:29:31 name rtkit-daemon[3537]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
12:29:32 name rtkit-daemon[3537]: message repeated 2 times: [ Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.]
12:29:33 name firefox_firefox.desktop[63518]: [ERROR glean_core] Error setting metrics feature config: Json(Error("EOF while parsing a value", line: 1, column: 0))
```